# MethodNotAllowedHttpException on form submit

Tags: laravel

I have some problem with my form::open with laravel 5.5
 i am getting error

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

This is my addressescontroller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'addressline'=>'required',
        'city'=>'required',
        'state'=>'required',
        'zip'=>'required|integer',
        'phone'=>'required|integer',
    ]);

    Auth::user()->address()->create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('checkout.payment');
}
```

this is my route

```
Route::get('payment','CheckoutController@payment')->name('checkout.payment');
```

.
this is my shiping-info.blade.php

```
   @extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
    <br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 small-centered columns">
        <h3>Shipping Info</h3>

        {!! Form::open(array('action' => 'checkout.payment', 'method' => 'POST')) !!}


   .....

 {{ Form::submit('Proceed to Payment', array('class' => 'button success')) }}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

when i submit the button code.. the error like above .. 
whats wrong ?

Comment: The controller method you posted has nothing to do with the rest of the question. The route you're posting to is posting to a method named `payment`, you posted method `store`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your route there is GET method defined

```
Route::get('payment','CheckoutController@payment')->name('checkout.payment');
```

But you are posting as POST method.

So please change

```
Route::post('payment','CheckoutController@payment')->name('checkout.payment');
```

Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Route::post('payment','CheckoutController@payment')->name('checkout.payment');
```

insted of

```
Route::get('payment','CheckoutController@payment')->name('checkout.payment');
```